# Kentico transformation textbox value in macro

Tags: transformation, kentico

I have a Kentico transformation with a text box and a button that fires a custom macro method that requires I pass the value in the text box.
How can I access it using k#?

```
<input type="text" name="foo"/>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="<%# CustomMacroMethod(~foo.value~) %>" >Button</asp:LinkButton>
```

Is there a way to access this value?

Comment: First thing first, you cannot use Macro in ASCX transformation. Macro can only be used in HTML environments. So you will need to use API in there.

Also, are you trying to pass a value to there or are you trying to get the value from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to access this properly is to:

1. create a custom static method,
2. add a [custom transformation method](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/adding-custom-methods-to-transformations) calling that custom static method,
3. add the macro method calling that custom static method.

This may seem like it's overkill but it allows you to use that same code throughout the site and the API.

Comment: Are you saying there is no simple way to access the contents of a textbox within a  transformation? Surely that's not true...

Comment: I'm simply stating this would be a best practice.  You can create a method within the transformation to do the work although the page lifecycle of Kentico is different than standard asp.net forms so what you might expect to happen most likely won't unless you create a transformation method or a custom control to handle this.  Take a look at the ecommerce transformation that has the Add to Cart button in it.  This should give you a good idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using transformation and you want to use macro - you need to call macro resolver

<%# CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve("{% CustomMacroMethod(~foo.value~) %}")

Google "Resolving macros inside transformation"  there are tons of answers.

Comment: The macro works just fine. I've tested it with default values. The issue here is getting the Contents of the textbox and passing it as a parameter!